# How to get top n% from a data using google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

From a data of people's height, I want to know how one can get top n% of people height. for example we have a height of 50 people and want to know the height of top 1% tallest people using google sheet

Comment: Try to do it with reverse formula, obtain the total count * 1%, then you should the number of count you need to obtain top 1%

Comment: 1% of 50 people is ... quite impossible! Let's talk about 10%.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming list of people is in column A, and height of each in column B

```
=query(A:B,"select A order by B desc limit " & round(counta(A2:A)*0.1) ,1)
```

I took here a percentage of 10%